# What to call someone who falsely accuses you?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, pejorative-language

One Word. A person that falsely, without valid proof, accuses you of something, such as a statement or act you said or did. Either because of his lack of knowledge about the proof or because of intent.

Comment: Why do you need a single word for this?

Comment: Most of the answers given so far cover the case where the accusation is made with intent.  OP also asks for the case of *lack of knowledge*.  In that case, you might say he's just *ignorant* if you want to give him the benefit of the doubt, or if you wish to *give a little back* you could call him an *ignoramus*.

Comment: @KitFox Is it important that we/you know why the OP wants a single word? If he says _because I want to shout XXX at my neighbour_ or _because I want to report a XXX to the police_ would the word XXX be different?

Comment: @Frank Yes, those things could be different words. Mostly, it is to elucidate why "a person who has falsely accused me of something" fails to meet the user's needs.

Comment: @KitFix It fails to meet his needs because it's not a single word which is what he asked for, but I'll agree that some context maybe would have reduced the _opinion-based_ choices. Thanks.

Comment: Nobody here has yet mentioned *troll*, the internet-specific manifestation of this delightful type. While not all trolls are intent on defamation, admittedly, a great many of them do seem to enjoy spreading gossip, rumour and slander online.

Comment: A calumniator one who will "utter maliciously false statements, charges, or imputations about 2. to injure the reputation of by calumny" http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/mwc/8670/calumniate

Comment: [Related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment16076_4732).

Comment: Too bad this question is closed. :( I was looking for the same thing too and after considering slanderer and defamer, I considered **backbiter** as well. Sounds familiar, casual, and 'street talk' while not deviating too much from the original meaning. Hope this helps someone else looking for the same word.

Answer (score 5):

To falsely accuse to deflect attention away from yourself onto another is to *[frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frameup)* them.  The person would be a framer.

> :  to devise falsely (as a criminal charge)
>
> :  to contrive the
>   evidence against (an innocent person) so that a verdict of guilty is
>   assured

You could say that the person was [fabricating](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fabricate) a plan against you too.  The person would be a fabricator.

> someone who tells lies
>
> invent or concoct (something), typically with deceitful intent.

---

And the following usually work too.  Since someone accusing you of doing something you didn't is damaging your reputation.

[calumniator](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/calumniate)

> charge falsely or with malicious intent; attack the good name and
>   reputation of someone

In the right situation the following work too:

- slanderer
- defamer
- smearer
- denigrator
- sullier

Comment: 'Calumny, slander, libel, defamation, sullying, and denigration' are all committed with the intent of damaging someone's reputation.  'Smear' could possibly be accidental. But I am wondering if there is a word for simply giving false evidence against someone (perhaps with the intention of deflecting suspicion from oneself).

Comment: @WS2 - I will edit with another choice, but these fit the question.

Comment: @WS2 - An accusation, as required by the OP's question, implies intent of damaging someone's reputation. How would giving false evidence not damage someone's reputation? Are you thinking of something along the lines of 'false witness'?

Comment: @davoid - I agree.  The legalise terms I have here encompass a wide array of harm.  I think any could fit but the OP would have to be more specific.  I added frame to appease the other side.

Comment: "To falsely accuse to deflect attention away from yourself onto another is to frame them." I disagree. Framing involves the notion of **guilt/innocence**. Simply deflecting attention from yourself to another is not framing.

Answer (score 2):

- **Slanderer** - someone who deliberately tells lies that will damage your reputation
- **Libeller** - slandering in print
- **Perjurer** - slandering under oath, or other specific legal circumstances

Of course, **liar** covers all these and more.

**Famacide** (a killer of reputation) is a nice one too.

Although not one word, you could have fun combining more than one of the above.

> "You **devious famacidal slanderer**!" cursed Marie as the angry mob turned their back on her twin sister and turned their weapons on her instead.

Comment: You basically just combined three answers already given.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd, I believe mine is the only answer to mention **famacide**, and the simple **liar**.

Comment: A liar is a person who does not tell the truth, and gives false information. It's not specific to the OP's request.

Answer (score 2):

If done with lack of knowledge about the proof, this person is merely a [slanderer](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/slanderer?s=t) or [defamatory](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Defamatory?s=ts) person.

However, if with [deliberate intent to harm or ruin another's reputation](http://www.ciao.ch/f/relations/infos/a26dea54bd8611dea0ad2d2fe7e6df2cdf2c/8.8.%20plus2-diffamations_et_calomnies-attention/), they are referred to as [calumniators](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Calumniator?s=t).

Comment: You just listed an answer I had an hour ago.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd Your original answer was a mere enumeration of adjectives without specific information on how these terms differ from each other. Mine makes the distinction between "defamation" and "calomny" apparent to the OP. So, claiming the opposite would be considered calumnious considering you modified your original answer after I posted mine.

Comment: So when offering word choices it is OK to use another answer as long as you add an "er", "or", "ing", "s", "es", and so on to the end?  I mentioned this because it seems common practice to you.

Answer (score 1):

**Libeller** - one who accuses falsely and maliciously, or publishes any false and defamatory statement in conversation or otherwise.

From the OED:

> One who libels another; one who publishes a libel or libels.

From the OED a definition of the verb *libel* is:

> To defame or discredit by the circulation of libellous statements; to
>   accuse falsely and maliciously

And a definition of the noun *libel* is:

> In popular use: Any false and defamatory statement in conversation or
>   otherwise.

Comment: I think that committing libel implies that the false accusations are published, such as in a newspaper or pamphlet. If the person who makes these accusations never puts it in writing, then I think they would be a *slanderer*.

Comment: In Media Law there is certainly a distinction between the two terms, in that libel is written calumny and slander spoken. However, in popular use the distinction is less clear, as evidenced in the OED definition above of libel as 'any false and defamatory statement in conversation or otherwise.' Slanderer is equally as applicable.

Answer (score 0):

**[Delator](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proxemics?ref=dictionary&word=accuser#)** is a professional accuser

> to blame (someone) for something wrong or illegal : to say that
>   someone is guilty of a fault or crime

Comment: OED's latest citation for *delator* is 1874, and their latest citation for any sense of the verb *delate* that's not explicitly identified as "obsolete" is 1863, so I don't think this answer is of much relevance. Having said that, I continue to be amazed by how many obscure words you manage to post (and indeed, by just *how* obscure they are! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: many more comments like that and one might start to suspect that you're a delator specializing in pointing out answers consisting of obsolete words. There you go, publish that and  OED can cite from 2014 if it chooses ;-)

Comment: @Steve: I might just email OED a link to your comment!  Seriously, I doubt *this* OP is interested in unknown/archaic words (I suspect he just wants modern insulting slang), but it *could* be relevant for others looking at this page. And I can't deny I'm becoming increasingly fascinated by the breadth of ThirdNews's vocabulary! :)

Answer (score -2):

I would call him **detractor**, **advocate**, **noxious**,**enemy**.

Comment: Detractor is close but the rest do not seem to address the question.