# someone who tricks you to hate someone else

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

What is the term for a person who hurts himself but makes you think someone else did it so that you hate that other person?

Comment: In soccer/football this is called flopping or diving https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diving_(association_football)

Comment: [Related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4842/2085).

Comment: I'd call him/her a really nasty person.

Comment: Not exact answers, but may convey the message: **deviousness** and **indirection** (Lack of straightforwardness and honesty in action).

Comment: A term taken from Shakespearean drama is "[an Iago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iago)."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to call someone who falsely accuses you?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172514/what-to-call-someone-who-falsely-accuses-you)

Comment: A "manipulator" controls ​people to ​their own ​advantage, often unfairly or dishonestly, but the word don't convey the idea of hurting oneself.

Answer (score 1):

A [*false-flag attack*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_flag) is where a nation attacks its own citizens, then blames it on someone else. This is normally done to justify starting a war on a weaker adversary that wishes to avoid a conflict they will inevitably loose.

The name *false-flag* comes from navel warfare. Ships often use false-flags to trick other ships into letting them pass, or to get close to an enemy before launching a surprise attack.